# Live wire in wall hard to trace

Tags: junction

I have what I believe is a low voltage conversion “box” above my basement drop ceiling. Two regular size wires go in, and small thin blue wires come out to the first floor kitchen to power under the cabinet lights.

I want to remove it because we are redoing the kitchen. Problem is, the wires go all over the place and to places I can't get to. It's impossible to remove it to the box. The drop ceiling is so close to the joists, and part of it is finished with drywall.

I don't mind removing the box and terminating the wires in a junction box, just worried it will continue to leach power off the panel. Is that even a thing?

[image: low voltage power supply housing in drop ceiling]

Answer (score 1):

There is no leaching of power. Electricity will only flow if there is supply at one end and a load (light fan etc) at the other end,  and if its turned on.

Comment: except in this case it sounds like that box is holding a power supply with AC line voltage entering and DC low voltage coming out...    I think even without a load a power supply will still draw power.

Comment: Makes sense.  Im removing the box completely.  Thinking of just terminating wires there in a new junction box instead of fishing back to the panel.